# Optimization with Lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum value of $xyz$ when $(x,y,z)$ is constrained to be in the intersection of the planes $10x+20y+10z=450$ and $4x+2y+3z=115$.

Comment: You should show what you tried

Comment: Formed the Lagrangian F(x, y, z) = xyz+\lambda (10x+20y+10z-450)+\mu (4x+2y+3z-115).
Setting the partial derivatives of the Lagrangian F with respect to x, y, z and equate them to 0, we get yz+10\lambda +4\mu = 0, xz+20\lambda +2\mu = 0, xy+10\lambda +3\mu = 0 where \lambda and \mu are Lagrangian multipliers.

Comment: Please use MathJax formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

From the first linear constrain one gets $x=45-2y-z$. Substitute into the second linear constraint so that :

$z=65-6y$

and also $x=4y-20$

Therefore we see that the intersection of the two planes is the line $(4y-20,y,65-6y)=(-20,0,65)+y(4,1,-6)$, parametrized by the real parameter $y \in (-\infty,-\infty)$.

So, as expected, it is possible to express two variables (x,z in this case) as a linear combination of the remaining one (y in this case). The bad news is that this forces f to be a cubic polynomial in y. Explicitly, on that line f assumes the values $-y(4y-20)(6y-65)$ and such a polynomial is unbounded from above and from below. No minimum nor maximum exists and the local maxima and minima provided by the Lagrange formalism would not provide any information, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Any comment from the OP ?